# как в c# с помощью условия узнать ли имеет значение переменная (любое значение)

Tags: c#, переменные

```
string a = "test";
if(a==true){
label.text = "true";
}
```

с таким кодом пишет Неявное преобразование типа "bool" в "string" невозможно

Comment: нужно именно строковое? или вообще любой тип?

Comment: как насчет `if (a!=null)` ? или `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))`?

Comment: В C# не бывает переменных без значений. Можно с определённой натяжкой считать `null` отсутствием значения, но вообще-то это такое же значение, как и другие.

Comment: Возможно, подойдёт сравнение с [default](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если касается только строки, то можно использовать [IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) 
    Console.WriteLine("is null or empty");
```

пример из доков:

```
class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
    string s1 = "abcd";
    string s2 = "";
    string s3 = null;

    Console.WriteLine("String s1 {0}.", Test(s1));
    Console.WriteLine("String s2 {0}.", Test(s2));
    Console.WriteLine("String s3 {0}.", Test(s3));
    }

    public static String Test(string s)
    {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) 
        return "is null or empty";
    else
        return String.Format("(\"{0}\") is neither null nor empty", s);
    }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       String s1 ("abcd") is neither null nor empty.
//       String s2 is null or empty.
//       String s3 is null or empty.
```

Comment: Спасибо всем! но как быть с переменными типа int и другими?

Comment: @AnonimAnonim У int не бывает "без значения", т.к. есть дефолтное значение (ноль) -- вам же писали об этом в комментариях к вопросу. И ВладД писал про то, что с некоторой натяжкой можно считать null для int? как "значение не установлено".

Comment: @AnonimAnonim огласите весь список пожалуйста) в целом максимум что нужно, это проверка на null - для reference типов, например экземпляр какого-то класса.... а вот всякие int, float  по умолчанию инициализируются числом